# Convert int to string in specific format

Tags: c#

I have a int which I want to convert to string in specific format.

For example,
-1 to -01:00

It is easy if I have positive number (i.e 1 to 01:00). I can use following code:

```
var time = 6;
var convertTime = "0" + time + ":00";
```

Output:

```
06:00
```

I am not sure how to achieve same with negative number.

```
 var time = -6;
 var convertTime = /* what to do here */ + time + ":00";
```

Desired Output:

```
-06:00
```

Comment: `var convertTime = "0" + time + ":00"` will yield a wrong value if `time` is greater than 9

Comment: It'll never be. Max is 6 based on functionality. Good point though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `string.Format` for that

```
int time = -6;
var convertTime = string.Format("{0:00}:00", time);
```

Or if you have C# 6 you can do an interpolated string.

```
var convertTime = $"{time:00}:00";
```

Comment: Look over https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx for what the options are for a format string.

Comment: @juharr Perfect. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
var time = (myInt*100).ToString("00:00");
```

Or if using C# 6 (VS2015):

```
var input = -6;
var time = $"{input:00}:00";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var time = -6;
var convertTime = (time < 0 ? "-" : String.Empty) + Math.Abs(time).ToString("D2") + ":00";
```

Comment: If you use the `D2` formatter then you don't need to do an absolute and the whole checking for the sign, just `var convertTime = time.ToString("D2") + ":00";`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example utilizing TimeSpan.

```
public void TestTimeSpan()
{
    var ts = new TimeSpan(-1, 0, 0);
    var s = string.Format("{0}{1:hh\\:mm}", ts < TimeSpan.Zero? "-": string.Empty, ts);
    Assert.AreEqual("-1:00", s);
}
```